# Javascript function settings/options styling questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, settings

I'm sure there are more elegant and shorter ways to write a similar piece of code.
What I'm trying to do here is passing slightly different parameters to even and odd elements inside a forEach loop.

```
  if (i % 2) {
    var myFuncSettings = {
      setting-name-1: setting-value-a,
      setting-name-2: setting-value-b,
      setting-name-3: setting-value-c,
    }
  } else {
    var myFuncSettings = {
      setting-name-1: setting-value-a,
      setting-name-2: setting-value-b,
      setting-name-3: setting-value-z,
    }
  }

  $(this).myFunc(myFuncSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that changes is the value for `setting-name-3`, so you can just put a ternary on that property:

```js
$(this).myFunc({
  'setting-name-1': settingValueA,
  'setting-name-2': settingValueB,
  'setting-name-3': i % 2 ? settingValueC : settingValueZ,
});
```